A solution procedure by "Fourier-Laplace transform" to Airy function (from oscillatory to exponential behavior)?
In studying the Airy equations (with final objective is to find the asymptotic behavior of the oscillatory solution to growing (frequency $\omega\to\infty$) decaying ($\omega\to0$) exponential behavior). Part of motivation is also due to the attempts to answer this interesting post Oscillatory and exponential behaviour of second order ODE.
The material I was reading is this Lecture Note.
On page 24 (page number 117), it claimed that using a Fourier-Laplace transform. Here it is the first time I ever seen the term Fourier-Laplace transform which the author might intended to be Fourier/Laplace transform or just Laplace transform?
From eq(4.38): $$u(z)=\int_Ce^{z\xi}f(\xi)d\xi.$$
The following step below it: "Then, assuming we can diﬀerentiate under the integral sign and integrate by parts, we ﬁnd that"
$$
-\frac{d^2u}{dz^2}+zu=\int_Ce^{z\xi}\left(\xi^2f+\frac{df}{d\xi}\right)d\xi
$$
where the bracketed is the Airy equation. Honestly it took me days to figure out the mysterious IBP method.
What is the motivation behind and why it was formulated by this (confusing) approach (in stead of the forward Laplace transform as this excellent answers pointed out)? That answer can solve part of my concerns but if any more comprehensive ones are greatly appreciated.

If you want to construct $\text{Ai}$, then a usual Fourier transform suffices. Indeed, up to a multiplicative constant, it is the only tempered solution to the Airy equation. You can then do a forward transform to convert the equation in Fourier space, solve it (it is now first order) and then transform back to get $\text{Ai}$. The issue is that it does not allow you to get all solutions since in general you have a $\text{Bi}$ component that grows exponentially and is therefore not tempered anymore.
The issue with the Laplace transform is that it only works for causal functions, since you only integrate over positive numbers. Furthermore, it does not allow you to study $\text{Bi}$ due to its too rapid growth. Once again, you are stuck with only getting $\text{Ai}$. In fact, it is even worse, since to apply the Mellin inversion formula, you have growth requirements on the transform, and you can only recover the null solution (the only causal one).
Taking the bilateral Laplace transform does not make things better either, as the for the forward transform, you add the divergence for negative values.
To summarise in all cases, due to the too rapid increase of $\text{Bi}$, all of the forward transforms are ill defined. This is why you need to reverse engineer the problem directly from the inverse transform and guess from which functions you get the Airy function. The proposed ansatz is similar to the usual Fourier method, but by allowing different contours, you can recover new solutions.
Hope this helps.
